# Docker container does not restart even when exit code is 1 and restart policy is always

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file with one service configured to `restart: always`:

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  zigbee2mqtt:
    image: koenkk/zigbee2mqtt
    restart: always
    network_mode: "host"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/app/data
      - /run/udev:/run/udev:ro
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    environment:
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    devices:
      - /dev/ttyUSB1:/dev/ttyACM0
```

**UPDATE:** Updating according to my comment: removing *network_mode: host* doesn't solve the case.

Each time this container crashes, it stays crashed and does not restart. Usually the restart policy works fine but I can't make it work in this case.

```
zigbee2mqtt_1  | Zigbee2MQTT:info  2021-11-24 07:07:58: MQTT publish: topic 'zigbee2mqtt/bridge/state', payload 'offline'
zigbee2mqtt_1  | Zigbee2MQTT:info  2021-11-24 07:07:58: Disconnecting from MQTT server
zigbee2mqtt_1  | Zigbee2MQTT:info  2021-11-24 07:07:58: Stopping zigbee-herdsman...
zigbee2mqtt_1  | Zigbee2MQTT:error 2021-11-24 07:07:58: Failed to stop Zigbee2MQTT
```

Where can be the problem?

Docker version: `19.03.7, build 7141c199a2`

Answer (score -1):

Have you try to remove this line :

```
network_mode: "host"
```

I think it's not very useful and saw lots of other topics having some issues because of this option.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Even if I remove `network_mode: host`, when the process exits with `code 1`, the container remains down until manually started: `docker-compose ps`  `zigbee2mqtt_zigbee2mqtt_1   docker-entrypoint.sh /sbin ...   Exit 1`

Comment: This has nothing to do with the service restart policy. It's one of the possible network configs and should not create any problem.